# How to include also folder in tsc output directory

Tags: javascript, typescript, build, tsc

Here is my project structure.

```
 - routes
   - index.tsx
 - package.json
 - tsconfig.json
```

I'm using `tsc` to build my project `tsc` is outputting files fine but it's not adding `index.js` in the routes folder.

here is my typescript config:-

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Language and Environment */  
    "target": "ES2022",                        /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    "experimentalDecorators": true,            /* Enable experimental support for TC39 stage 2 draft decorators. */
    /* Modules */ 
    "module": "CommonJS",                      /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "moduleResolution":"node",
    "outDir": ".randoms",                      /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                   /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,  /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
    "strict": true,                            /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                       /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */,
    "baseUrl": ".",                            /* base directory path */
    "paths": {  "@/*": ["./*"]  }              /* path alias */
  },
  "include": ["."],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
  // "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  // "exclude": ["node_modules"],
}
```

> how can i make typescript compiler so it also add `routes` folder to output directory.

[image: SS]

Comment: ```tsc --rootDir . --outDir .randoms``` works for me if anyone knows a better approach please do not hesitate to answer this question.